# How to use a value from an element to set the interval in setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, casting, jquery-events

I have a page that shows the people that accepted to come to an event along with some details about them. These people accept by filling in a form which is then submitted to a database. My page basically makes an AJAX request to it and fetches all the relevant data which then sorts them out to a readable layout.

I am trying to add the option for the person viewing this page to set a refresh rate - that is, the time before remaking the AJAX request each time. For instance one may choose 30 seconds, so the page each time 30 seconds pass makes another AJAX request and overwrites the old data...

What I did was have dropdown box with some choices (60secs, 120secs, and so on). 
When the section loads the javascript containing the AJAX call gets the value from the dropbox and uses it as a parameter in the setInterval function, like this

```
recurring = setInterval(function() {
                            getSchedule(dateText.trim());
                        },
                        $('input[type=hidden]#rr').val());
```

but the requests are non-stop. At first I thought the problem may be that the result of the JQuery selection is string when the argument expected should be number so I tried

```
recurring = setInterval(function() {
                            getSchedule(dateText.trim());
                        },
                        parseInt($('input[type=hidden]#rr').val(),10));
```

but still nothing.
I don't know if it means anything but when testing this code (when I was trying to see what type the value was)

```
var interval = parseInt( $('input[type=hidden]#rr').val() , 10 );
alert( typeof ( interval ) + ' -- ' + interval );
```

the alert box writes

> number -- NaN

Any ideas anyone?

Okay, this is an edit to show the html code

```
<div class='fields'>
    <input type='hidden' name='rr' id='rr' value='<?php if ( $_SESSION['rr'] != 0 ) echo $_SESSION['rr']*1000; else echo 86400000;  ?>'/>
    <div style='float:left; padding-top:5px;'>
        <b><i>TIME</i></b>
    </div>
</div>
<div id='schedule' style='overflow:auto;'>
</div>
```

This is the section where the data is presented. The AJAX result goes into the schedule div and is the one updated. The hidden field contains the milliseconds for the interval and is where I get it from using JQuery. It is in a database stored and when this page is loaded there is some communication with the database and get it from there and the save it in the session array

Comment: i don't understand why you are trying to get a hidden value if its a select box. maybe you should post select box code aswel.

Comment: show us the actual html that appears in the browser, we can't tell what your php code is outputting. It would be useful enough to show us what `$('input[type=hidden]#rr').val()` is (without calling parseInt)

Comment: is this what you are after? http://jsfiddle.net/Pevara/LW4HM/1/

Comment: please inspect the page when you load it and check that value in the html it might contain nondigits or empty

Answer (score 1):

once you use the `setInterval`, unless you explicitly call `clearInterval`, it will [continue](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) to call the your function.

Instead, I'd recommend you should use `[setTimeout]` like this

```
setInterval(function () {
    getSchedule(dateText.trim());
},
$('input[type=hidden]#rr').val());
```

and in your function `getSchedule`, call setInterval again. This way, every time the function executes, it sets the time period for itself.

```
function getSchedule(...){
   ...
   setInterval(function () {
        getSchedule(dateText.trim());
    },
    $('input[type=hidden]#rr').val());
}
```

As far as the input value is concerned, I cannot comment until I see your HTML

Comment: This is a good solution for if the refresh rate might change but in my case the refresh rate is set in a different page (I changed a little how it works because it didn't really matter and it would take longer). Interesting thought though, using setTimeout and the function calling itself. Thanks. Doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: Hmm, what if you change the page but remain in the same domain. Wont the function keep calling itself. The way I did it was that each time a page in the website loaded was to check the url (from some get values). If the page was not the one with the schedule I called clearInterval

Comment: Or if the javascript containing the function is not loaded in the same page the setTimeout won't be able to find something and it will cause an error and it will stop?

Comment: JavaScript will only work on the page where it is present. It wont work if you visit another page from the same domain. Same is the case with setTimeout and setInterval etc. They work as long as the page that called them is loaded in the browser. The moment you browse away from that page, all the script is unloaded. So you don't have to worry about function keep calling itself when you browse away from your page.

Comment: Can you do View Source of your page and see what is the value in your hidden input field? I am guessing, it is not a valid number.

Comment: The value is what I would expect. In any case I tried using setTimeout and works fine now, but now if a user selects a different date a new setTimeout occurs resulting in two ajax calls and if another date is selected I now have three AJAX calls. I can use clearTimeout I think but I was wondering... If I set the setTimeout function to a global variable, then each time another setTimeout is set to that variable will the previous one remove itself?

Comment: no you have to clear the queue of that timeout as you are doing, or it will be executed anyways

Comment: yeah, tested it and saw it... just one line before the call

Answer (score 0):

[updated]
A few comment's that might help but not solve your problem:

for your selection, since you are using id, you should select directly (faster) :

```
parseInt($('#rr').val()); // by default the base is 10
```

note: you don't have to use typeof since you are always parsing to int, it will be always a number

I think maybe your problem is related to that value, does it exist? can you inspect the page and check what the value is as an html ?

Comment: I don't think this it what it is. I already have the $(document).ready() in my code. Also, I am under the impression that any php values are filled in the html document in the server and then that final html document is what is sent to the client. The only way for the value to not have returned is in the case of an AJAX call

Comment: that's true, how absurd of me  ,, check maybe session['rr'] doesn't have a value, if it does try parsing it to a number before comparing it

Answer (score 0):

So I never did understand why the value was read wrong, maybe the browser used the cache and loaded javascript before the changes... Anyway my final solution with the help of the above that works is the following

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker( {
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        inline: true,
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
                getSchedule(dateText.trim());
        }
    });

    var timeout;
    var today = $('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate');
    getSchedule($.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', today));
});

function getSchedule(date)
{   
    if ( 'undefined' === typeof(timeout) ) ; else clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                            getSchedule(date);
                        },
                        parseInt($('input[type=hidden]#rr').val(), 10)
                        );


    var request = $.ajax({
        type    : 'POST',
        url     : './scripts/php/schedule.php',
        data    : { date: date }
    });

    request.done(function(data,textStatus,jqXHR) {
        var height = $(window).height()-150;
        $("#schedule").height(height).html(data);
        }
    });

    request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    }); 
}
```

and the html

```
<div class='fields'>
        <input type='hidden' name='rr' id='rr' value='<?php if ( $_SESSION['rr'] != 0 ) echo $_SESSION['rr']*1000; else echo 86400000;  ?>'/>
        <div style='float:left; padding-top:5px;'>
            <b><i>TIME</i></b>
        </div>

</div>
<div id='schedule' style='overflow:auto;'>
</div>
```